# How to find recent N consecutive records in a table using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table definition with table name "JOBS" and sample data as below:

```
| job_name |   created_on   | result |
| -------- | -------------  |--------
|    x     |  2021-01-20    | fail   |<-
|    y     |  2021-01-01    | success|
|    y     |  2021-01-02    | success|
|    x     |  2021-01-22    | fail   |<-
|    z     |  2021-03-15    | fail   |<-
|    z     |  2021-03-11    | success|
|    z     |  2021-03-16    | fail   |<-
|    x     |  2021-01-18    | fail   |
|    z     |  2021-01-03    | fail   |
|    x     |  2021-01-19    | success|
```

I need to find recent consecutive jobs which are failing back to back N times sorted by descending order of date of creation. This is applicable for each job group in the table.

E.g. if N=3, I need to find job names with three recent back to back failures with date in descending order(recent dates).

For above table, the result should be

```
| job_name |   created_on   | result|
| -------- | -------------- |
|    x     |  2021-01-22    | fail  |
|    x     |  2021-01-20    | fail  |
|    z     |  2021-03-16    | fail  |
|    z     |  2021-03-15    | fail  |
```

In Above case, N=2(i.e number of consecutive job failures for each job group)

I tried using lag, lead, partition by, but couldn't find the exact solution.

I tried below query for N=2.

```
select distinct(m.job_name)
    from (select t.*,
                 lag(result) over (partition by job_name order by created_on) as prev_result,
                 lead(result) over (partition by job_name order by created_on) as next_result
          from JOBS AS t
          order by created_on DESC
         ) m
    where result = 'fail' and
          'fail' in (prev_result, next_result)
    order by m.job_name;
```

Comment: please show some of the things you tried?

Comment: by "recent dates", do you mean the latest N dates are all fail?  or there are N consecutive fails in the last some number of days or records?  if there are two non-consecutive dates with fail but no success record between them, does that count as consecutive?

Comment: Recent dates in the sense top dates after sorting these in descending order. I need to check only consecutive jobs which are failing. e.g. if N=3, I will get job names with three back to back failures.(date sorted in Descending order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be divided into three parts and could be solved progressively.

1 - Get most recent success result dates for each job_name, so that jobs after that dates could be fetched.

```sql
SELECT j2.job_name, max(j2.created_on) mdate 
FROM jobs j2 
WHERE j2.result = 'success' 
GROUP BY j2.job_name
```

2 - Get all rows that have failed status and whose `created_by` is after last successful job.

```sql
WITH last_success_date AS (
  SELECT j2.job_name, max(j2.created_on) mdate FROM jobs j2
    WHERE j2.result = 'success' 
    GROUP BY j2.job_name
) 
SELECT j.* FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN last_success_date lsd ON j.job_name = lsd.job_name
WHERE j.result = 'fail' AND j.created_on > lsd.mdate
```

3- Get only results that have more than n successive failed results

```sql
WITH failed_jobs AS (
  WITH last_success_date AS (
    SELECT j2.job_name, max(j2.created_on) mdate FROM jobs j2
      WHERE j2.result = 'success' 
      GROUP BY j2.job_name
  ) 
  SELECT j.* FROM jobs j
  LEFT JOIN last_success_date lsd ON j.job_name = lsd.job_name
  WHERE j.result = 'fail' AND j.created_on > lsd.mdate
) 
SELECT fj.* FROM failed_jobs fj
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT fj2.job_name, count(fj2.id) fail_count FROM failed_jobs fj2
  GROUP BY  fj2.job_name
) AS with_counts on with_counts.job_name = fj.job_name 
WHERE fail_count >= 2 ORDER BY fj.created_on DESC
```

I used `n=2` in above example.
[db fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f67bd0f2f9c4dabd350baeecb67e5001)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT *,
                 SUM(result = 'success') OVER (PARTITION BY job_name ORDER BY created_on) grp
          FROM jobs ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT job_name, grp, COUNT(*) cnt
          FROM cte1
          WHERE result = 'fail'
          GROUP BY job_name, grp
          HAVING cnt >= @N )
SELECT cte1.*
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 USING (job_name, grp)
WHERE cte1.result = 'fail';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a2e64d7b19980535183560c6fab9c776) with some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated subquery.  Assuming success and fail are the only values:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.created_on > all (select t2.created_on
                          from t t2
                          where t2.job_name = t.job_name and
                                t2.result <> 'fail'
                         );
```

An alternative using window functions gets the maximum `created_on` for a "success" and uses that for filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when result = 'success' then created_on end) over (partition by job_name) as max_success_created_on
      from t
     ) t
where created_on > max_success_created_on or max_success_created_on is null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90a58dac0911cf6715c035a787ff7b3f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This query return only the last two consecutive result "fail" rows for each job:

In first query "jobs_fail_groups" I mark rows of consecutive jobs with the same result with a number (each group with a number calculated).

Then in second query "jobs_fail_groups_selected" I `GROUP BY job_name, grupo` selecting only rows with result 'fail' and groups with count(*) >= 2.

In third query "result" I JOIN previous queries USING job_name and grupo and calculate row number for each job.

Finally I get the first two rows of each group.

```
WITH jobs_fail_groups AS (SELECT  
                                 *,
       
                                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY job_name, created_on DESC) - 
                                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY job_name, result ORDER BY job_name, created_on DESC) AS grupo
           
                             FROM jobs
                             ORDER BY job_name, created_on DESC),
                             
     jobs_fail_groups_selected AS (
                          SELECT job_name, grupo, count(*)
                          FROM jobs_fail_groups
                          WHERE result = 'fail'
                          GROUP BY job_name, grupo
                          HAVING count(*) >= 2),
                          
     result AS (SELECT
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY job_name ORDER BY job_name, created_on DESC) AS `order`,
                       jfg.*
                FROM jobs_fail_groups jfg
                INNER JOIN jobs_fail_groups_selected jfgs USING (job_name, grupo))

SELECT r.job_name, r.created_on, r.result
FROM result r
WHERE `order` <= 2;
```

This query has some similarities with some of the other queries, but It is not completely the same.

Answer (score -3):

```sql
select
  t5.job_name,
  t5.created_on,
  t5.result
from
  (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by t4.job_name order by t4.created_on desc) as rn
    from
      (
        select
          t3.job_name,
          t3.created_on,
          t3.result
        from
          (
            select *, row_number() over (partition by diff) as failed_times
            from
              (
                select
                  *,
                  overall_rn - row_number() over (order by created_on desc) as diff
                from
                  (
                    select
                      *, row_number() over (order by created_on desc) as overall_rn
                    from jobs
                    order by created_on desc
                  ) t1
                where t1.result = 'fail'
              ) t2
          ) t3
      ) t4
  ) t5
where
  rn <= 2;
```

The above query will meet your requirement, window functions makes such task easier